# Webpage rendering time/loading libraries

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rendering

I'm writing an offline html document to practice my HTML/CSS/JS skills. This document isn't hosted on a webserver or anything, but I can still make hrefs and load libraries online.
Well, I wanted to incorporate JQuery and JQuery UI in my document and the vastly dominant piece of code to make this happen seems to be this:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

But this line of code has the nasty effect of increasing my document rendering time from none to 20 seconds.
This solution on the other hand:

`<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script> google.load("jquery", "2.0.3"); </script>`

renders the document almost immediatly and then my $(document).ready function works properly. So my question is:
Why do everybody opt for the first option, and why do google recommend it? What is the difference between those two? Are there other better ways?

As a bonus yes/no question: I've been trying to create a simple text-based game, but as it is I have to restart the game whenever I refresh the page. Does it make any sense for me to experiment with cookies with my offline-document? Save/load functions, login credentials?

Comment: if you aren't running on a webserver and instead are running from the filesystem, `//domainname.com/etc` will result in a 404 (and a delay while the browser attempts to get said non-existant file). add `http:` before it. `//` without the protocol, such as `http` is a reletive protocal request, similar to a relative domain request in that it will use whatever protocol is currently being used. In this case the current protocol is file://, so it will look here: `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js` which is a location on your hard-disk rather than on the web.

Comment: Okay well, I didn't understand much of that. But prefacing my URLs with "http:" totally helped! Thanks a lot! :)
- Also it appeared that my previous code didn't load the library at all: I was under the false assumption because the variable "footer" which i declared in the document.ready function was also the id of my footer. Apparantly you can just say footer.innerHTML = something. 
So I wonder what the getElementById is for :O